# Thought and emotional processes in converting?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, psychology

Seeking written material on the cognitive and affective aspects of converting to Judaism.  Are there commonalities among many or most converts to Judaism?  What motivates one to convert? Are there typical sequences of thought or emotional states during and after the conversion process?  Is regret typical or rare?  Seeking authoritative sources.

Comment: This is very interesting. I have a lot of thinking about this from personality study point of view  but I am not sure that there is an Halachic study about this. Anyway, 2 things I remember. Vaychat Ytro, naasse besaro chidudim, and about Eshet Yefat Toar, she cry her father.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is Jews, not Judaism.